# How to print a specific part of response.content

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm making a cellphone tracer and I want to be able to organize all of the information I have from a response.content.

I've tried doing print(response.content[9:13]) (as an example) but I realized every phone number will have a different location and It won't fit properly

```
if valid_confirm_loop=='valid':
    print('Number is Valid')
    print('Country Prefix: ' + response.text[121:123])
    print('Country code: ' + response.text[141:143])
    print('Country Name: ' + response.text[161:185])
    print("City: " + response.text[199:206])
```

> **{"valid":true,"number":"xxxxxxxxxxx","local_format":"xxxxxxxxxxx","international_format":"xxxxxxxxxxx","country_prefix":"+1","country_code":"US","country_name":"United States of America","location":"Seattle","carrier":"Cellco Partnership (Verizon Wireless)","line_type":"mobile"}**

This above is when I do print(response.content). I want it to be organized as

Country: Country name.
City: City name.
etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the response content which is in text format to json and use and get the variables you want. Example below:

```
import json
response_json = json.loads(response.content)
country_prefix = response_json.get('country_prefix', "")
country_code = response_json.get('country_code', "")
country_name = response_json.get('country_name', "")
city = response_json.get('location', "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json #import json
responseContent = b'{"valid":true,"number":"xxxxxxxxxxx","local_format":"xxxxxxxxxxx","international_format":"xxxxxxxxxxx","country_prefix":"+1","country_code":"US","country_name":"United States of America","location":"Seattle","carrier":"Cellco Partnership (Verizon Wireless)","line_type":"mobile"}' #sample content

data = json.loads(responseContent) #convert bytes to json 

for key, value in data.items(): 
    print(key, " : ", value)
```

The result will be:

```
valid  :  True
number  :  xxxxxxxxxxx
local_format  :  xxxxxxxxxxx
international_format  :  xxxxxxxxxxx
country_prefix  :  +1
country_code  :  US
country_name  :  United States of America
location  :  Seattle
carrier  :  Cellco Partnership (Verizon Wireless)
line_type  :  mobile
```

Comment: This will get you the data the way you wanted @mutiny.